# Print statement in class getting executed even though there is no class instance/object

Tags: python

content of my python file

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def myfun(self):
        pass
    print ("hello world")
```

Output on executing file

```
hello world
```

Query

```
since I did not create object of class . How's it still able to print "hello world"
```

Comment: Anything inside a class is ran, just like if it was on the base indentation level.

Comment: is it python specific ? as per my understanding...anything class can not run until we call it by creating a object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class body executes at class definition time, and that's how the language is designed.

From section [9.3.1 Class Definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax) syntax:

> In practice, the statements inside a class definition will usually be function definitions, but other statements are allowed, and sometimes useful.

That is simply how the execution model works in Python, so there's not much more to say about it.

> as per my understanding...anything class can not run until we call it by creating a object

Simply a misunderstanding.  This applies for `def`, i.e. function blocks, but not for class blocks.

Answer (score 2):

It will get a call, as python work like that. 
Your code will always return output.

**hello world**

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def myfun(self):
        print("hello world")
        pass
```

If you want to avoid it you have to add print statement inside the method.